# how to get object when it pass in url?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sending a object in url with navigation  from one html to another .But while retrieving i am not able to get object.
I am sending a ajax request

// data is an object .when I send data which is object it will not retrieve object but When I send string it insert special characters .

```
var param1var = getQueryVariable("data");

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] == variable) {
            return pair[1];
        }
    }
    alert('Query Variable ' + variable + ' not found');
}
```

can you suggest how I will send data in when moving to another page.
one way is to store data in session or local storage .But I don't want to do that..I there any other solution instead of session or local storage ?

Comment: You need to serialise `data` before using it as a query string argument.

Comment: Why don't you want to use local storage? It is [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage), and the easiest way of persisting data between pages. Otherwise, you can fallback to cookies for small amounts of string data, or use something server-side.

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
var query = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1));
```

it will not return special characters.

Comment: so I will send as a string or object

Comment: it will return as a string